# Mod sequences that seem to become constant; and the number 316

Tags: nt.number-theory, integer-sequences

Define a "mod sequence" of nonnegative integers
based on one start parameter $s$, its first term,
as follows.
$A(s)=(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n,\ldots)$
with $a_1 = s$
and
$$ a_n = \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k \right) \bmod n\;.$$

For example, $A(13)=(13, 1, 2, 0, 1, 5, 1, 7, 3, 3, 3, \ldots)$.
Here is how this is obtained.
Let $S(s)$ be the sums, $s_n=\sum_1^{n} a_k$.
Then $S(13)=(13, 14, 16, 16, 17, 22, 23, 30, 33, 36, 39, \ldots)$.
In detail,
$$a_2 = 13 \bmod 2 = 1$$
$$a_3 = 14 \bmod 3 = 2$$
$$a_4 = 16 \bmod 4 = 0$$
$$a_5 = 16 \bmod 5 = 1$$
$$a_6 = 17 \bmod 6 = 5$$
$$a_7 = 22 \bmod 7 = 1$$
$$a_8 = 23 \bmod 8 = 7$$
$$a_9 = 30 \bmod 9 = 3$$
$$a_{10} = 33 \bmod 10 = 3$$
$$a_{11} = 36 \bmod 11 = 3$$
$$a_{12} = 39 \bmod 12 = 3$$
And all remaining terms are $3$.

> **Q1**. For all $s \ge 1$, does $A(s)$ become a constant after some finite $n$, $a_n=c$?

Here is a bit more data, showing for each $s$ (first row), the constant reached (second row):
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
   & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
 97 & 97 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 &
   2 & 316 & 316 & 2 & 2 & 3
   \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
The constant $316$ seems especially ubiquitous, always (apparently) reached at $a_{1241}=316$.
For $s \le 50$, $316$ is reached for 
$$s=\{9,10,33,34,37,38,39,40,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50\}\;.$$
For $s=9$, $s_{1241}=392472$ and $(392472 \bmod 1241) = 316$;
then $s_{1242}=392788$ and $(392788 \bmod 1242) = 316$; etc.

> **Q2**. What is special (if anything) about $316$?

---

**Addendum**.
Here is an image that shows which $s$ map to which $a_n=c$,
for all $s \le 100$.
The upper-right cluster is $316$.
The leftmost cluster is $13$, nearly as ubiquitous as $316$;
so perhaps I misled to single out $316$....

---

[image: ModSeqs100]

---

Comment: You might consider listing the possible mod sequences that can occur.  There are 2 possibilities for a_2, and 3 for a_3, but maybe not so many for a_6.

Comment: If $a_n = a_{n+1}$ for some $n$, we are done, beacause then $s_{n-1} \equiv 0 \mod (n+1)$, so $s_{n-1} = x(n+1)$ and $a_n = x$. So we have $s_n = x(n+2)$, $a_{n+1} = x$, $s_{n+1} = x(n+3)$, $a_{n+2} = x$ and so on...

Comment: More generally, if $s_{n-1} = x_n (n+1) + b_n$ with $0 \leq b_n \leq n$, then $a_n = x_n + b_n - n \epsilon_n$ where $\epsilon_n := 1_{x_n+b_n \geq n}$ and then $b_{n+1} = 2b_n + 2 \epsilon_n \hbox{ mod } n+2$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n + \lfloor \frac{2b_n - n \epsilon_n}{n+2} \rfloor$. As Istvan observed, as soon as $b_n$ hits zero one gets a constant sequence, so the puzzle is why $b_{1241}=0, x_{1241}=316$ occurs so often.  The latter is at least not so puzzling: we expect $a_n$ to be $n/2$ on avg, so concentration of measure predicts $s_n \sim n^2/4$ and $x_n \sim n/4$.

Comment: Since $x_n \sim n/4$, $\epsilon_n \approx 1_{b_n > 3n/4}$, so I guess what is going on is that the dynamics of $b_{n+1} = 2b_n + 2 1_{b_n > 3n/4} \hbox{ mod } n+2$ has an unusually large collapse to zero near $n=1241$.

Comment: @Istvan, that doesn't work when a_1 is a reasonably sized factorial.  There are other exceptions when a_n is larger than n^2.

Comment: @The Masked Avenger, yes, we need the condition, such that $x_n < n$, but by growing rate of $s_n$ its eventually true.

Comment: Waouh ! That should interest Don Knuth, who wrote a book entitled *3:16*.

Comment: Your $a_n$ are each computed $\mod n$; does the $A(s)$ sequence still appear to become constant if you use a different increasing sequence for each $a_n$, e.g., $\mod p_n$ where $p_n:=$ the $n$th prime? (If these sequences also become constant: How do they compare to the ones computed here?) The same could be asked $\mod n^2$ etc...

Comment: @BenjaminDickman: Your sequences with $\bmod p_n$ do not appear to become constant, at least not relatively quickly, for any $s$.

Comment: The sequence cannot become constant in the $\pmod{p_n}$ case, for any starting value $s>0$.  To see this, suppose by way of contradiction that it did become the constant sequence $c\pmod{p_n}$ for every $n>N$.  This would mean that $s_N+(m-1)c\equiv 0\pmod{p_{N+m}}$ (for *each* $m\geq 1$), and hence $p_{N+m}|(s_N+(m-1)c)$.  But $p_{N+m}\sim (N+m)\log(N+m)$ while $s_N+(m-1)c\sim cm$, so the primes grow too fast to continue dividing.

Comment: However, in the original $\pmod{n}$ case, we would expect the sequence to almost always stabilize due to the following heuristic.  Assuming that the dynamical system given by the $b_n$'s in Terry's post are random, the chance that going from $b_{n-1}$ to $b_{n}$ yields $0$ is approximately $(1-1/n)$.  [I believe there are some local restrictions, based on whether $n$ is even or odd, but I'm ignoring those for simplicity.]  Since $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-1/n)=0$, we get the stated expectation.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I think this is the same as your latter observation, just slightly restated: Even in JO'R's original problem, assuming randomness, the chance of getting a number to appear for a second time in a row is $1/n$ for step $n$ (really beginning at step two, so your product counter would start at $n=2$). As István observes, a number appearing twice in a row is sufficient for the sequence to become constant. So the probability of no repeats is $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} (1-1/n) \rightarrow 0$. There would need to be a major conspiracy for there never to be any repetition...

Comment: Some data. For $s \in \{933,934,939,940,943,944,947,948,949,950\}$, after $n=292735$ iterations, $a_n$ settles at the constant $73190$.

Comment: To produce data where $a_n$ settles for different $s$  like for $s = 167771 \ldots 167788$  $a_n$ settles afte $n=292511$ iterations at 73118. the following Mathematica routine is helpful. Probably Q1 is equivalent to the statement that this program stops for all $s$.
Clear[S];S[s_, 1] := s; S[s_, n_] := S[s, n] = S[s, n - 1] + Mod[S[s, n - 1], n];
    ModSeqSettle[s_] := Module[{n = 2}, 
  While[Mod[S[s, n - 1], n + 1] != 0 || S[s, n - 1]/n > n - 1, 
   n++] ; {n, S[s, n]/(n + 2)}]

Answer (score 10):

Before this becomes another forgotten open problem on MO, let me record here a comment. An equivalent way to state the sequence is as follows: Let $x(1)=2s-1$ and look at the recurrence equation:
$$x(n+1)=x(n)+x(n)_{\operatorname{mod}n}$$
where I'm using $x_{\operatorname{mod}n}$ to mean the smallest nonnegative integer equal to $x$ mod n. You get essentially the same sequence if you start with $x(1)=2k$. Now the question in the OP is equivalent to:

> **Question:** Is this sequence eventually an arithmetic progression?

The common difference of this progression is the convergent value of your sequence. This conjecture was mentioned in  [A117846](https://oeis.org/A117846).

Moreover, the OEIS also includes a slightly more general conjecture in [A074482](https://oeis.org/A074482): Suppose $x(1,k)=s$ and
$$x(n+1,k)=x(n,k)+x(n,k)_{\operatorname{mod} n+k}$$
is this always eventually an arithmetic progression? What can we say about the common differences as a function of $s,k$? The mysterious 316 doesn't appear prominently anymore for different $k$, but the values do tend to concentrate around other seemingly random numbers. The oeis links have a lot of computed values in case anyone wants to hunt for patterns.

Comment: Nice to see $316$, $97$, et al. show up in A117846!